# Python: Using List items in place of Global Variables

Tags: python, multithreading, list, variables, global

So I've been curious. I'm sooooomewhat new to python. I've been coding for over a year or so, but something I covered but didn't totally understand was the stigma that "global variables are bad."

That said, I was a beginner and couldn't understand any of the online explanations as to why I should avoid (or just be careful with) global variables. I just took everything everyone said to heart, and made the assumption that global variables are simply sinister monsters that prowl my code during runtime and eat all my data.

So I began to do the following:

```
>>> SomeVar = [0]     # To avoid the 'global' keyword, I'll just make a single list item.
>>> 
>>> def increment():      # Hey look, it's practically global!
>>>     SomeVar[0] += 1
>>> 
>>> increment()
>>> increment()
>>> 
>>> SomeVar
 [2]
```

After some time, I finally have the knowledge and experience to do some actual research on the matter, an I'm starting to get the impression I *may* have missed the point. I know globals take up namespace, can present issues in multithreading, and too many of them and/or too many functions accessing them at once can get hard to keep track of, but there's enough I still don't understand about them that I just wanted to ask;

Does my list-global-aversion variable actually help with the *any* of the issues global variables can present, or did I totally miss the point? I can see why it wouldn't do any good with the aforementioned issues, (multithreading, spaghetti code) but... does it help at all?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `SomeVar` *is* a global variable. The only thing you avoided is to use the `global` keyword.

Comment: In your example, if you type `globals()`, you'll find that SomeVar, whether it's a list or just a number, appears in the global dictionary. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've missed the point.  What you created is still a global variable; all you did was work around the keyword.

When this expands to a full program, the initialization of `Somevar` is likely to be widely separated from its usage.  You've left your function dependent on an external variable of unknown location and provenance.  instead, try this:

```
def increment(var):      # Hey look, it's properly local!
     return var + 1

somevar = 0
somevar = increment(somevar)
somevar = increment(somevar)
```